# How to set up authorization in freeradius for a captive portal divided into admin and user

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authorization, freeradius, captiveportal

I'm trying to set up freeradius authorization for my captive portal. I use:
as a WIFI router openwrt-22.03 + coova-chilli;
freeradius 3 + postgresql;

```
`radius=# \dt
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | macs          | table | postgres
 public | nas           | table | postgres
 public | nasreload     | table | postgres
 public | radacct       | table | postgres
 public | radcheck      | table | postgres
 public | radgroupcheck | table | postgres
 public | radgroupreply | table | postgres
 public | radpostauth   | table | postgres
 public | radreply      | table | postgres
 public | radusergroup  | table | postgres
(10 rows)


radius=# select * from radcheck;
 id  |        username         |     attribute      | op |   value
-----+-------------------------+--------------------+----+-----------
 326 | admin                   | Cleartext-Password | := | admin
 327 | magicbook               | Cleartext-Password | := | 33467784


radius=# select * from radusergroup;
 id | username  | groupname | priority
----+-----------+-----------+----------
  8 | admin     | admin     |        0
  9 | magicbook | user      |        0
(2 rows)

radius=# select * from radgroupreply;
 id | groupname |  attribute   | op |        value
----+-----------+--------------+----+---------------------
  1 | user      | Service-Type | := | Framed-User
  2 | admin     | Service-Type | := | Administrative-User


radius=# select * from macs;
 id | username  | callingstationid
----+-----------+-------------------
 25 | admin     | 8C-7A-3D-90-07-08
 27 | magicbook | 7C-C2-C6-1F-49-EE
(2 rows)`
```

I create a captive portal myself in the js language - https://github.com/Pavewleln/captive_portal. Website on html/css/js
I also have my own server on Nodejs + expressjs, which processes everything that comes from the site and sends it to freeradius and vice versa.

Don’t ask why these technologies, I didn’t choose them, it’s necessary.

I seem to have the simplest authorization configured, just by username + password. I also have additional authorization configured by MAC address, but it is currently disabled.
I set it up using this source - https://gist.github.com/nasirhafeez/6669b24aab0bda545f60f9da5ed14f25#user-mac-binding

I want to configure authorization for a regular user and an admin user. As I understand it, you need to use groups, or simply add another attribute to radcheck that can be used to check. But when I put something in a radusergroup, the username that the group is associated with will no longer be logged in.

```
`RADIUS request:  {
[1]   code: 'Access-Request',
[1]   secret: 'testing123',
[1]   attributes: [
[1]     [ 'User-Name', 'magicbook' ],
[1]     [ 'User-Password', '33467784' ],
[1]     [ 'Calling-Station-Id', '8C-7A-3D-90-07-08' ]
[1]   ]
[1] }
[1] RADIUS response: {
[1]   code: 'Access-Reject',
[1]   identifier: 137,
[1]   length: 36,
[1]   authenticator: <Buffer d2 5d 8c e9 a5 39 77 f8 a2 1b b1 10 2d 2b 56 8d>,
[1]   attributes: { 'Reply-Message': 'Wrong Password' },
[1]   raw_attributes: [ [ 18, <Buffer 57 72 6f 6e 67 20 50 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64> ] ]
[1] }`
```

This is an example of what I receive from the site, and what freeradius responds to me. (The code can be viewed here https://github.com/Pavewleln/captive_portal (server/controllers/user.controller.ts)).

I understand that most likely I’m not setting up groups correctly in freeradius, but I don’t understand how to set them up then, how can I implement an admin and a regular user.

How can I fix this, how to properly configure authorization, as well as admin and user authorization.
If there are other customization options, then I'm willing to give up this one.
I would be incredibly grateful if someone could post an example of a similar captive portal, also based on nodejs.